# Is there any way to ignore-platform-req all but keep one in composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

Let's say I've config like this in the composer.json

```
"require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.164.*"
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
},
```

Now once I run `composer install --no-dev -W -o` its errors out like these.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - aws/aws-sdk-php[3.164.0, ..., 3.164.1] require ext-simplexml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's simplexml extension.
```

I can `--ignore-platform-req=ext-simplexml` and it solves the issue but errors out for other extensions are missing.

like `ext-json, ext-pcre` is missing.

To resolve this, I can do this `--ignore-platform-req=ext-simplexml --ignore-platform-req=ext-json --ignore-platform-req=ext-pcre`. But in my case, there are a lot of missing extensions, so I don't want to go with this approach.

Note: If I resolve the issue by ignoring all the extensions for this package, then its errors out similar missing extensions for its dependent packages as well.

If I do this `--ignore-platform-reqs` then it will ignore all the requirement checking, including PHP which I added in my composer.json

So I'm looking if there is any way to exclude platform checking with a wildcard. Something like this `--ignore-platform-req='ext-*'` (this doesn't work)

Comment: What do you mean by "all but keep one"? If you want to avoid such checks, disable them. But there might be consequences, like some stuff could not be working

Comment: @NicoHaase Let's say I've set PHP version like this. If I set `--ignore-platform-reqs` then it will ignore this PHP version checking too. So what I wanted, to keep the PHP version checking but ignore all other platform checking.

Note: Those extra platform checking comes from other packages, which I don't have access to.

` "config": {
  "platform": {
   "php": "5.6"
  }
 }`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I don't think that this config section is parsed from other packages

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using a wildcard is not supported in the option `--ignore-platform-req`, yet.

There currently seems to be no way to ignore all platform dependencies except for PHP itself.

I have created [an issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10045) for this in the official repository.